# How to upgrade from 14.04.4 to 14.04.5?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, stable-release-updates

What steps should I take to upgrade from 14.04.4 to 14.04.5?
I haven't got any update notifications till now.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 9):

There won't be any special notifications for this.  Just do the standard updates.

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: If I have 14.04.3 installed, will dist-upgrade upgrade to 14.04.5, or to 16.04? I would like to upgrade just to 14.04.5, not to 16.xx!

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` will NOT upgrade the release.  Release upgrades are performed with the use of `do-release-upgrade -d` which is a completely different command.

Comment: Stormlord: in your answer to the OP, 2 days ago, you said that `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade from 14.04.4 to 14.04.5! So my question was simple: will 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' upgrdae from 14.04.3 to 14.04.5, too? (that's what I need). Note that "do-release-upgrade -c" answers that it will upgrade to: 16.04.1 LTS (which I don't want)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Going from 14.x to 16.x is a release upgrade.  Going from 14.04.4 to 14.04.5 is a release update and it's done as explained in my answer.

Comment: I asked about going from 14.04.3 to 14.04.5; _not_ from 14.04.4 to 14.04.5

Comment: It's the same thing.  The system will be updated to the last one even if you start from 14.04.

Comment: I was about to ask a question on going from 14.04.4 to 14.04.5, because for me  `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not work and I seem to be stuck at the Feb 18, 2016 upgrade version 14.04.4.

Comment: Is there an solution this question? This answer *blatantly* doesn't work.