# Stuck at point-release 14.04.4 (HWE upgrade path issue for 14.04.5 ?)

Tags: 14.04, updates, hardware-enablement-stack

*[ Ubuntu 14.04.4 desktop LTS with automatic updates enabled - boot with BIOS ]*

When running:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[normal output - no error]

$ sudo apt-get -y upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[same as above]
```

For reference:

```
$ uname -a
Linux HOSTNAME 3.16.0-50-generic #67~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
Fri Oct 2 22:07:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a | grep -i descript
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
```

I remain stuck at 14.04.4, the 2016-02-18 Trusty point-release.
My system is stable, but it won't budge from point-release version 14.04.4, and it's been weeks since I last got even a security update. Updates are installed from:

- Important security updates (**trusty-security**)
- Recommended updates (**trusty-updates**)
- Unsupported updates (**trusty-backports**)

*"trusty-proposed" is off.*

Packages are downloaded from the internet via:

- Canonical-supported free and open-source software (**main**)
- Community-maintained free and open-source software (**universe**)
- Proprietary drivers for devices (**restricted**)
- Software-restricted by copyright or legal issues (**multiverse**)

Mining the web for answers, I did find [one instance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808529/how-to-upgrade-from-14-04-4-to-14-04-5) of the same issue. I eventually got to [one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes) of the Trusty release-notes page. Quote:

> By default, the 14.04.5 point release will ship with a newer 4.4 Linux
>   kernel from Ubuntu 16.04, and a matching X.org stack. This is based on
>   the 4.4.0 Extended Upstream Stable Kernel Release. The purpose of
>   providing a newer kernel in the 14.04.5 point release is for hardware
>   enablement.

and also:

> Anyone wishing to opt into the hardware enablement stack for Trusty
>   may do so by running following command which will install the
>   linux-generic-lts-xenial and xserver-xorg-lts-xenial packages:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
>   libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial`
>   and

The cmd yields:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

Posts [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216287/unable-to-install-files-with-apt-get-unable-to-locate-package),[[4]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt) (...) on the subject were not helpful, although in the latter @minerz029 recommends going to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) with a web browser to "Search package directories". Packages' availability results are:

- Package linux-generic-lts-xenial
  Exact hits:
  trusty-updates (kernel): Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
  4.4.0.36.26: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el
- Package xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial
  Exact hits:
  trusty-updates (x11): Xorg X server - core server
  2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.2~trusty3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
- Package xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
  Exact hits:
  trusty-updates (x11): X.Org X server
  1:7.7+13ubuntu3~trusty2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
- Package xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial
  Exact hits:
  trusty-updates (x11): X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
  1:7.7+13ubuntu3~trusty2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
- Package xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
  Exact hits:
  trusty-updates (x11): X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
  1:7.7+13ubuntu3~trusty2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
- Package libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
  Exact hits:
  trusty-updates (libs): implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
  11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el

All packages are available. And I am still stuck. **I'd like to understand**.

***EDIT:***
I also [found](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) [image: ubuntu kernel release schedule]

Not sure but it may point to one inconsistency in my setup. I run on kernel *3.16.0-50-generic* which seems to correspond to release 14.10 and not to 14.04. **Is this an upgrade path issue ?** If so, how do I correct that ?

Comment: @edwinksl: thanks. Responding to yr previous (now erased) question, I do not have access to the cmd line tool `hwe-support-status`. Looking for it with  `dpkg-query -S hwe-support-status` returned zilch. -- About the bug you mention, Martin Pitt (pitti) wrote on 2016-08-02, that the fixed update-manager was to be shortly available in the `trusty-proposed` repo. So I enabled it on my box and ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and 24 packages related to language packs, dvd tools and printing resources were upgraded. Report on `apt-get dist-upgrade` to come...

Comment: ... and as before `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` returns nothing to upgrade.

Comment: Ah, it's okay, I don't think it would have helped much anyway. :/

Comment: ... and running the newly fixed `update-manager` from the Dash, still does not produce any result.

Comment: Can you do `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` to see if you have held any packages?

Comment: @edwinskl: None, I had checked it. The system appears "healthy" and stable, a necessity because that is the system I usually try things on not to mess up "hot" production boxes .

Comment: Intriguing. I am out of ideas for now. Hopefully someone will come along and figure this out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change mirrors for package updates. Suddenly I had a pending update of 350 packages accumulated over the past 12 months.

An few minutes after completion of that first round I had several security update and about an hour later a point-release update to 14.04.5.

It looks like my old mirror had not been updating its vault in the past year or so.